# Squid3 blocking all sites except restricted sites

Tags: proxy, http, squid

I have a configuration file and in the lines where I have my allowed and restricted sites, I have the following:

```
acl AllowedSites dstdomain "/home/john/squid3_sites/allowed-sites.squid"
acl RestrictedSites dstdomain "/home/john/squid3_sites/restricted-sites.squid"
```

And then on my `http_access` list, I have

```
http_access allow AllowedSites
http_access deny RestrictedSites
```

The Contents of my allowed-sites.squid is only a * to represent that all sites area allowed. And on my restricted-sites.squid there is only "www.facebook.com". The proxy restricts all sites except of facebook.com. When I go to any site I can think of, I get the error site with Access Denied. If it helps, here is my full `http_access` list:

```
http_access allow AllowedSites
http_access deny RestrictedSites
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny all
```

And all my acls':

```
acl SSL_ports port 443 563
acl AllowedSites dstdomain “/usr/local/etc/allowed-sites.squid”
acl RestrictedSites dstdomain “/usr/local/etc/restricted-sites.squid”
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 563     # https, snews
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl all src all
```

Answer (score 1):

Like lots of allow/deny rule based systems once a rule matches it is applied and there is no further processing of that rule chain. So once you allow * it never even gets to any subsequent deny rules for that chain. Or as the documentation says:

> Access list rules are checked in the order they are written. List
>   searching terminates as soon as one of the rules is a match.

Once you replace the * with the actual list it will work. You also don't need a deny sites list if your following it by a `deny all`.